# How to use COUNT to calculate number of occurence in two columns?

Tags: psql

I am having two tables.

Table 1: Consists of name of the players and their id's.

```
tournament=> select * from Players;
 id |  name
----+--------
  1 | Rahul
  2 | Rohit
  3 | Ramesh
  4 | Roshan
  5 | Ryan
  6 | Romelu
  7 | Roman
  8 | Rampu
(8 rows)
```

Table 2:Consist of both the opponents playing each other, column1 contains the name of the winner and column2 loser. So this means that both taking part in that Match.

```
tournament=> select * from Matches;
 id | winner | loser
----+--------+-------
  1 |      1 |     2
  2 |      3 |     4
  3 |      5 |     6
  4 |      7 |     8
(4 rows)
```

Now I want to count number of matches played by different players, I have counted the number of matches won by players by following query.

```
SELECT Players.id, COUNT(Matches.winner) AS Points FROM Players LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from Matches) AS Matches ON Players.id = Matches.winner GROUP by Players.id Order by Points desc, Players.id;
 id | points
----+---
  1 | 1
  3 | 1
  5 | 1
  7 | 1
  2 | 0
  4 | 0
  6 | 0
  8 | 0
(8 rows)
```

But I am not able to get the logic of how should I calculate the number of matches played by each player?

From above Matches table we can see that each players has played once but I am not able to write that in psql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query counts the winner and loser ID values in two separate queries which are then `UNION`ed together.  There is no worry of double counting because a team cannot play against itself, rather it can only play against another unique team.  The outer query sums the team counts.

```
SELECT t.id, COUNT(t.id) AS numMatches FROM (
    SELECT winner AS id FROM Matches UNION ALL
    SELECT loser AS id FROM Matches
) t GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: Getting Error:

`ERROR:  column "matches.winner" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:     select winner AS id, count(*) AS numMatches from Matches...`

Comment: Yeah it's working can you please explain a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

A simple nested subquery is needed, as follows:

```
SELECT pl.id,
(
    SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM Matches
    WHERE winner = pl.id OR loser = pl.id
) AS matches
FROM Players pl
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Your answer is working but I have given the correct answer to Tim.